# Infragistics UltraCombo will not populate data, although data is being retrieved

Tags: c#, winforms, infragistics

I have an UltraCombo box that I need to populate with data from a database query. Unfortunately, the data will not display no matter what I do. The UltraCombo is blank every single time the form loads. I have verified that the data is being retrieved successfully; I can print the query results from the same method that is supposed to populate the UltraCombo. I've tried explicitly adding the control to the Controls collection, and I've tried to define a DataMember for the control. Neither worked. I have rewritten the database methods multiple times to make sure they are compatible with UltraCombos. I am using .NET 4.7.0 and Infragistics 2021.2.

This is my code:

```
public partial class MainForm : Form
{
    public CurrentLayoutControl currentLayoutControl;

    public MainForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.currentLayoutControl = new CurrentLayoutControl();
        PopulateLayoutCombo();
    }

    public void PopulateLayoutCombo()
    {
        DataTable layouts = currentLayoutControl.LoadUserGridLayouts(suiteConnectionString);
        currentLayoutControl.DataSource = layouts;
        currentLayoutControl.ValueMember = "User_Grid_Layout_Id";
        currentLayoutControl.DisplayMember = "User_Grid_Layout";
    }
}


public class CurrentLayoutControl : UltraCombo
{
    public DataTable LoadUserGridLayouts(string connString)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string sql = "USE My_Database; SELECT User_Grid_Layout_Id, User_Grid_Layout FROM app.User_Grid_Layouts";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        conn.Open();
        dataTable = ExecuteQuery(connString, command);
        conn.Close();
        return dataTable;
    }

    private DataTable ExecuteQuery(string connString, SqlCommand command)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have `public CurrentLayoutControl currentLayoutControl;` (why `public`?), then `this.currentLayoutControl = new CurrentLayoutControl();`: I don't see you adding this custom control to a parent Container -- BTW, this: `DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();  [...] dataTable = ExecuteQuery(connString, command);`  doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 0):

I took a look at the example at : [https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid~infragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultracombo](https://www.infragistics.com/help/winforms/infragistics.win.ultrawingrid%7Einfragistics.win.ultrawingrid.ultracombo)

I noticed that you construct a `UltraCombo` control in memory but it has no representation on the `MainForm`.  You wipe it out when you call the UltraCombo constructor on it.

Here's what you need to try now.

1. Remove the call `this.currentLayoutControl = new CurrentLayoutControl();` -- this is wiping the designer one out.
2. Move the two methods from CurrentLayoutControl class and into the MainForm (like I show in the example below)
3. Get rid of the CurrentLayoutControl class.  you don't need it.  That class is wiping out the one in the designer -- Infragistics sets up stuff for you and this class wipes that out.
4. run it and it *should* work.

   public partial class MainForm : Form
   {
   public CurrentLayoutControl currentLayoutControl;

   ```
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            PopulateLayoutCombo();
        }

        public void PopulateLayoutCombo()
        {
            DataTable layouts = currentLayoutControl.LoadUserGridLayouts(suiteConnectionString);
            currentLayoutControl.DataSource = layouts;
            currentLayoutControl.ValueMember = "User_Grid_Layout_Id";
            currentLayoutControl.DisplayMember = "User_Grid_Layout";
        }
    public DataTable LoadUserGridLayouts(string connString)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString);
        string sql = "USE My_Database; SELECT User_Grid_Layout_Id, User_Grid_Layout FROM app.User_Grid_Layouts";
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);

        conn.Open();
        dataTable = ExecuteQuery(connString, command);
        conn.Close();
        return dataTable;
    }

    private DataTable ExecuteQuery(string connString, SqlCommand command)
    {
        DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
        adapter.Fill(dataTable);
        return dataTable;
    }
   ```

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work. The control was still blank.

Comment: Can you add the following as the 2nd line in PopulateLayoutCombo() ==> MessageBox.Show(layouts.Rows.Count.ToString(), "Row Count");   This will help us know that there are records in the layouts table.

Comment: @EthanMalloy  I updated my answer with something you can try. I believe you need to call the PopulateLayoutCombo() later in the event firing in the Load event.

Comment: @raddveus, the MessageBox shows 4 rows. I tried what you suggested, and it's still not working.

Comment: @EthanMalloy I've updated my answer again.  I believe you are wiping out the default Infragistics initilization (UI related stuff) and you need to use the control you dragged/dropped onto the form, but not Construct it again.  Try out my code and let me know.